# Let $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $f(0)=0$. Show that $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is in $C(\mathbb{R})$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity

I'm trying to solve the below problem. It's from an exam in real analysis. Thus, only such methods may be used.

> Let $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $f(0)=0$. Show that $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is in $C(\mathbb{R})$.

This is my attempt. Is it correct?

> We start by introducing the denotation $$g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{x}.$$ We may use L'Hôpital's rule since $f(0)=0$ and $x=0$, and both $f(x)$ and $x$ are continuous functions that form the quotient $0/0$ when $x=0$. Here
>       \begin{align*}
>   \lim_{x\to0}g(x)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f'(x)}{1}=f'(x),
>  \end{align*}
>       and $f'(x)\in C(\mathbb{R})$ since $f(x)\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$.
>
> The rule is applicable here as the numerator and the denominator only need to be differentiable separately, and the denominator needs to have a nonzero derivative on the domain. This also means that the limit only needs to be valid for the denominator and the numerator separately.
>
> This is true here as the denominator is $x$, and the numerator belongs to $C^1(\mathbb{R})$ by assumption. Thus, the limit exists and is the derivative of the function at that point.
>
> One way to do this is to say that by theorem a pair of continuous functions $f$ and $g$ form continuous functions $\alpha f+\beta g$, $fg$, or $f/g$, given that $g(x)\neq0$ for $f/g$, which was just covered.

Is there any other way to do the last part? I don't know if my professor will be fine with me just referring to some theorem in the book.

Comment: $\lim_{x \to 0} g(x) =f'(0)$ not $f'(x)$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Yeah! You're right. Does that ruin my argument?

Comment: You don't need L'Hopital: it follows from the definition of derivative alone that $$f'(0):=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}.$$ And thus the function $g(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{f(x)}x&\text{if }x\ne 0\\ f'(0)&\text{if }x=0\end{cases}$ is continuous. In fact, continuity of $f'$ is not necessary at all: continuity of $f$, $f(0)=0$ and differentiability at $0$ are all that is needed.

Comment: @Oskar Tegby Not at all!  Just complete the argument by saying that we can define $\frac {f(x)} x$ to be $f'(0)$ to get a continuous function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the fundamental theorem and the chain rule,
$$
f(x)=\int_0^1 f'(tx)x\,dt
$$
so that 
$$
\frac{f(x)}{x}=\int_0^1 f'(tx)\,dt
$$
and the right side is a continuous function of $x$.

Comment: Can one just divide with $x$ on both sides like that?

Comment: Yes, as it is an explicit factor on the right side.

Comment: Does that go for every integral equation? Say $$f(x)=\int_1^\infty f'(tx)5x^3dt\Leftrightarrow \frac{f(x)}{5x^3}=\int_1^\infty f'(tx)dt?$$

Comment: Yes, as that $5x^3$ is a constant factor in the integrand. Obviously, with a limit involved you have to care for existence which can make a difference in the divergence case for $x=0$.

Comment: Okay. Then I'm with you.

Answer (score 1):

The argument is almost correct. There's a typo in the line $$  \lim_{x\to0}g(x)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f'(x)}{1}=f'(x),
$$
it should be
$$\lim_{x\to0}g(x)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f'(x)}{1}=f'(0).
$$
Then we are done by saying that $f'(0)=\frac{f(x)}{x}$, as Kavi Rama Murthy pointed out.

Another approach given by Saucy O'Path is to note that $$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x},$$ and to define $$g(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{f(x)}{x} & \text{if}\ x\neq0 \\ f'(0) & \text{if}\ x=0 \end{cases}.$$ This is continuous as $f\in C^1(\Bbb{R})$ means that $f$ has a continuous derivative.

I hope that you are fine with me writing your comments as an answer to the question. If not, then I will delete this answer.

Comment: I'm confused. You just proved $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}g(x)=f'(0).$ But if and only if you can also prove (not just define) $g(0)=f'(0)$, then you may claim the continuity. Where is the proof for the latter?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but isn't that true by construction?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that the statement itself does **not** hold at all. Here is a counterexample.

Consider the situation when $f(x)=\sin x$. Then $f'(x)=\cos x \in C(\mathbb R),$ and $f(0)=0.$ But $\dfrac{f(x)}{x}=\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$ is not continuous in $\mathbb R$, because at least it has no definiton at $x=0$, even if $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\dfrac{f(x)}{x}=1.$ Actually, the discontinuous point could be removed by making a supplementary definition, but this is not an inevitable conclusion could be drawn from the assumptions.

Now,I wonder how you so many people could prove a false statement.

Comment: $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ is continuous. It equals 1 for x=0. Just use L'Hôpital to compute the limit as $x\to0$. Right?

Comment: No,you're wrong. Do you know so-called "removable discontinuity point" ?

Comment: Right! That's when $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists, but not $f(a)$. Mea culpa.

Comment: yes. and how do you know $f(x)/x=?$ when $x=0$?

Comment: L’Hôpital’s rule.

Comment: Hold on! It has a removable singularity there. Does that necessarily mean that it’s discontinuous?

Comment: I think so. that point itself has no definition.